# What Motived the Creation of Taylor Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion, approximation

Was there a specific problem that lead to need for developing Taylor Series?

I have (informally) heard that hundreds of years ago, people had difficulty calculating different things. This included:

- Logarithms
- Cube Roots
- Exponents where the power was a decimal number
- Complicated functions involving very large numbers
- etc.

I have also heard that these problems and difficulties lead to the development of different approximation methods to calculate these things, and the Taylor Series was one of these methods.

For example, suppose someone in the the 18th Century wanted to calculate the 4th Root of some large number (e.g. 999999) - using the Taylor Series, they could write this in general as "x^(1/7)", find the Taylor Expansion of this function around x = 999999, and finally calculate the approximation error bound relating to this calculation.

Is this correct?

Was the Taylor Series originally developed to approximate (and "bound") calculations that used to be difficult hundreds of years ago? Were there in fact some specific types of calculations that were giving people difficulties back then -  Or was the Taylor Series purely developed as a theoretical exercise with no intended applications to real world problems?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the details of the historical discovery, but it's well-known that the derivative represents the best linear approximation near a point. You could make higher order approximations by asking for polynomial expressions such that analogous limits are $0$. If you wrote this down, you'd find you'd written a Taylor polynomial. And if you calculated the difference between the approximation and the function, you'd get various forms of remainder.

Comment: Thank you! I was just curious to know if there were specific problems (e.g. in engineering, architecture, finance, etc.) that were troubling people hundreds of years ago, that lead to the need for Taylor Series - or whether Taylor Series were created just as a theoretical exercise? thanks!

Comment: The dedicated [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Taylor series are entirely practical.  How does you computer calculate $\sin 7$?  It uses a Taylor series.  If you are trading options, the options are valued using the Black-Sholes model.  If you are trading options, or bonds with imbedded options, in real-time, you do not have the time to recalculate your valuations as the inputs change.  However, using "the Greeks" we have a quadratic model that will give very accurate results very quickly.

Comment: It can be traced at least to the middle ages in India when series approximations were developed for trig functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_series

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama

Comment: The Taylor series was created by Nature, we have math analysis only because the Taylor series are primary. But historically, they have emerged as a result of the natural observation of functions through the prism of analysis.